# How to order items a dictionary in Python, based on part of strings contained in the values?

Tags: python, string, sorting, dictionary

I need to order the items in a `dictionary`, based on a the last characters of of the strings in the values.

For example, my dictionary is `{1:'001 abc',  2:'001 xyz',  3:'001 efg'}`

but I need to sort it so its `{1:'001 abc',  3:'001 efg',  2:'001 xyz}`

(the first part of the string in the values is identical, then a space, and the second part of the string could be used to sort the values alphabetically)

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use an ordered dict https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [ordered dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
for k, v in sorted({1:'001 abc', 2:'001 xyz', 3:'001 efg'}.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]):
    d[k] = v
d
>> OrderedDict([(1, '001 abc'), (3, '001 efg'), (2, '001 xyz')])
```

Comment: This can just be `new_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(old_dict.items(), key=lambda L: L[1]))` (eg: you don't need the for-loop and assignments)

Answer (score 0):

Dicts aren't sorted, so there's no way to "order the items in a dictionary."

But you can sort *the elements* in the dictionary however you like.

For example:

```
d =  { 1: '001 abc', 2: '001 xyz', 3: '001 efg' }

for key, value in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]):
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
```

**EDIT**

As others have pointed out, you can put the elements into an `OrderedDict` if you want to keep using them as a dictionary but preserve the sorted order.

If you want to do that, I'd suggest this code:

```
od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
```

**SECOND EDIT**

FYI, `operator.itemgetter(1)` can replace `lambda item: item[1]`. I'm not sure which I think is clearer.